# return result of Deque pollFirst() in java

Tags: java, deque

I was coding an algorithm issue, below code can't pass case

```
public void pop() {
    if (s1.pollFirst() == minStack.peekFirst())
        minStack.pollFirst();
}
```

however below can,

```
public void pop() {
    int tmp = s1.pollFirst() ;
    if (tmp == minStack.peekFirst())
        minStack.pollFirst();
}
```

the only difference is how I use s1,pollFirst() return result. I can't figure out real difference here.
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing two `Integer` Objects with values less than -128 or bigger than 127 using `==` will always result in `false`. However,  if you compare `Integer` with primitive `int`, it will give you `true` if the actual value is the same.

```
        int n1=128;
        Integer n2=127;
        Integer n3=127;
        Integer n4=128;
        Integer n5=128;
        System.out.println(n1==n2); //false
        System.out.println(n2==n3); //true
        System.out.println(n4==n5); //false
        System.out.println(n1==n5); //true
```

In the second example you are assigning the value to the primitive `int`, therefore it is automatically unboxed.

Comment: please add tags

Comment: It will not “always” result in false.  Integer objects outside of the -128, 127 range are not *guaranteed* to be cached instances, but Java implementations are *permitted* to cache values outside of that range.  What matters is that it’s not guaranteed, so it’s generally not safe to compare Integer objects with `==`.